# Violation of Gibbs Phase Rule?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

According to Gibbs phase rule, only one intensive property is required to completely specify a simple compressible system which is in a liquid/vapor equilibrium.

F = 2 + C - P

For a pure substance, C = 1
For a liquid/vapor equilibrium, P = 2

This gives F = 1

But is one property enough?

If we specify the temperature, don't we still need the quality to specify the state completely? Or am I missing some conceptual understanding of the topic?

Thanks!

Comment: You get to specify one. The system gets to specify all the others to be in equilibrium. You pick T, there will be only one P where you have equilibrium. You pick P, there is only one T where it holds.

Comment: @JonCuster But what about other intensive properties like specific volume, specific enthalpy and specific internal energy? They are only specified if we specify the ratio of the mass of vapor to the mass of liquid, right?

Comment: You asked about when phases were in equilibrium, not how much of each phase is present. Gibbs phase rule does not specify that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the one property is enough if it automatically determines a second property. For example, apply Gibbs phase rule to saturated steam. If you know T you know P and vice versa.

What's more you also know the intensive properties of specific volume v ($m^3/kg$), internal energy u ($kJ/kg$), and enthalpy h ($kJ/kg$) for the liquid and vapor phases at a given T (or related P). You can find them in the saturated steam tables.

You only need the quality of the steam to determine the related extensive properties, volume (V), internal energy (U), and enthalpy (H) of the liquid and vapor phases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We also need the quality of steam for specific volume of the liquid vapor mixture, right? and specific volume is an intensive variable

Comment: Yes.  To find out how much is liquid and how much is vapor (and thus the total specific volume) you need the quality plus the values from the steam table.

Comment: I still don't quite find the answer convincing. Often, the derivation of the Phase Rule shows that the +2 in F = C-P+2 comes from the fact that since we have the constraint ƒ(P, v, T) = 0, we can always find the third one by defining the 2 other variables. But what about at the phase boundary? On the PT graph, you see it as a line. Yet in PvT space, you see it as a plane where you can vary v at constant P and T, and therefore requires 3 variables to define a state (disregarding the P and T relationship at the phase boundary which C-P in the equation will deal with). Am I missing something?

Comment: @JY_Decipherer_  The $P$ and $T$ in the $PvT$ space are intensive properties. Total volume $V$ is not, it depends on the mass. You vary $V$ in $PVT$ for constant $P$ and $T$ space for a two phase pure component system because $V$ is an extensive property.  But the specific volume $v$ is fixed.

Comment: Yes, the specific volume v is fixed for each phase, but what about the specific volume of the 2-phase system? We can imagine 2 scenarios where the temperature, pressure and amount of substance are the same, but one with mostly liquid, and the other mostly vapour. Clearly we can see that the specific volume of the latter is larger than the former, yet we don’t consider them different from each other in the phase rule.

Comment: @JY_Decipherer_ "Yes, the specific volume v is fixed for each phase, but what about the specific volume of the 2-phase system?" You need the quality of the mixture to determine that.

Comment: Does that mean that the quality of the mixture does not count as a degree of freedom? And why?

Comment: @JY_Decipherer_ If you want to continue this discussion, set up a Chat room, as it may get too lengthy to carry out under comments.

Comment: @JY_Decipherer_It appears that in applying the phase rule the quality is not considered a degree of freedom, only pressure or temperature, even though it (quality) is needed to determine the fractions of the mixture that are vapor and liquid.

Comment: For example, in the following link

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/gibbs-phase-rule

there’s the statement: “If the pressure is given, the temperature is directly known and therefore the state of the system in each phase is determined. However, the quality of the two-phase system, which is the fraction of vapor in the saturated two-phase mixture, is not known and is needed to find the relative amount of one phase with respect to the other. This type of substance has one degree of freedom”

Comment: I believe the key phrase here is “state of the system in each phase is determined”, which means the specific properties of the vapor and liquid, for example $v_g$ and $v_f$, and opposed to $v$ of the mixture, where $v=xv_{g}+(1-x)v_f$. But I acknowledge there is some ambiguity which appears to be rooted in whether or not it is legitimate to talk about specific properties of the mixture, because the mixture is not “homogenous”. There is a distinct boundary between the vapor and liquid phases.

Comment: For example, in the following link

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/gibbs-phase-rule-use-for-wet-vapour.892448/

Boundary makes the following statement: “For application of the phase rule vapor is saturated or it is not; you don't have the option of looking at the average density of ‘wet steam’. That is not a variable you can arbitrarily include in the degrees of freedom.”

Comment: Finally, in the following link, both sides of the issue are addressed. 

https://www.quora.com/According-to-the-Gibbs-phase-rule-F-1-in-vapor-dome-it-means-that-with-one-variable-we-should-be-able-to-fix-the-state-but-we-are-talking-about-one-more-variable-dryness-fraction-into-account-Does-it-mean-phase-rule

In the answer by Saikrisha Nadella he/she says if it is assumed the mixture is homogenous, then there are two degrees of freedom, if not (the real case), one degree of freedom. 

This is about as far as I go in responding to your doubts. You’ll have to draw your own conclusions.

Comment: One last point. The quality is needed because it is the first step to determine the extensive properties of the mixture, total volume, internal energy, etc. . The second step being information on the mass of the mixture. The extensive properties of the mixture don't involve the homogeneity of the mixture, only that  the phases are in equilibrium.

Comment: @JY_Decipherer_ Sorry if my answer to your question was rather lengthy. But it can be summed up as follows. If, in fact, quality was a degree of freedom in Gibb's Phase Rule then, in the case of water, we would have no choice but to say the number of phases is one. But as I understand it, the definition of a "phase" for the rule is  "a form of matter that is HOMOGENEOUS in CHEMICAL COMPOSITION and PHYSICAL STATE” would mean that the vapor liquid mixture is homogenous, which clearly it is not.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to write such a detailed answer (I always appreciate a lengthy response). I think I'm quite convinced by the first half of your answer, especially the statement “state of the system in each phase is determined” is what the phase rule describes, though I'm not certain about the latter part in which the answer in [quora.com/...](https://bit.ly/3tHgBwD) explains how to interpret the phase rules in 2 ways in order to include the quality. Although the method works at phase boundaries, I don't think it works at the triple point as both methods don't seem to add up to 1.

Comment: I'm actually not quite familiar with what happens at the triple point (how do you even define the "quality" at the point?), so I might be wrong. But I'd much rather accept that the phase rule is defined the way it is, and maybe I can just make up my own new phase rule where I add 1 DoF at phase boundaries or triple points: it's just a matter of definition I guess. Once again, I thank you for making time to research for the response and going back to such an old question.

Comment: @JY_Decipherer_ No Problem. I don't think quality applies to the triple point since it is a single point on the PT diagram, as opposed to saturated steam where there is  a range of possible amounts of each phase. So my guess is that at the triple point the amount of each phase must be fixed, though I admit I am not sure.  This might help:http://sv.rkriz.net/classes/MSE2094_NoteBook/96ClassProj/OLD/examples/triplpt.html

Answer (score -1):

By definition, the degrees of freedom, F, in  Gibbs phase rule designates the number of intensive independent properties that must be specified to fix the state of a system for each phase not the state of a system itself.
Shah M Hasan, I think you are right, the state of the mixture as system is not fixed completely only by determining its pressure or temperature.
Indeed, we have two kinds of intensive properties: phase-intensive properties such as: specific volume of each phase i.e. vf and vg, and system-intensive properties such as quality. Pressure and temperature are both phase-intensive and system-intensive properties.Gibbs phase rule is about the number of phase-intensive properties rather than system-intensive properties.
see:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037838129087009E

Comment: A system at equilibrium is at thermal, mechanical, and chemical equilibrium in **all** phases. Your analysis neglects this fact.